# Verificar se existe um campo dentro do Json

Tags: php

Bom sei como recuperar um campo dentro de um Json, eu faço assim:

```
$json = '{
 "operacao": {
    "nome": "hugo"
 }
}';


// Decodifica o Json
$obj = json_decode($json);


echo $obj->operacao->nome;
```

Porém como posso verificar se o json esta faltando o campo `nome`?
Exemplo:

```
$json = '{
 "operacao": {

 }
}';
```

Comment: `if(isset($obj->operacao->nome)){ ... }`?

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
// Decodifica o Json
$obj = json_decode($json);

if(isset($obj->operacao->nome)) {

    // O valor existe

}
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: Será um problema se o valor de `$obj->operacao->nome` for igual a `null`, o resultado da operação `isset` será `false` mesmo existindo a propriedade.

Comment: É verdade @FilipeMoraes, obrigado pela explicação! +1

Answer (score 6):

É possível utilizar a função `isset`, entretanto há um porém se o valor atribuído for nulo:

```
<?php 
$json = '{
    "operacao": {
    "nome": "João"
 }
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

if( isset( $obj->operacao->nome ) ){
    echo "Existe a propriedade";
} else {
    echo "Não existe a propriedade";
}

//resultado: Existe a propriedade
```

Porém a propriedade pode existir mas com um valor nulo, por exemplo:

```
$json = '{
     "operacao": {
     "nome": null
   }
}';

//resultado: Não existe a propriedade
```

Repare que a propriedade existe mas o resultado foi negativo. Isso ocorre porque a função `isset` determina se a variável foi definida e não é nula.

Nesse caso utilize a função `property_exists`:

```
if( property_exists( $obj->operacao, 'nome' ) ){
    echo "Existe a propriedade";
} else {
    echo "Não existe a propriedade";
}

//resultado: Existe a propriedade
```

No caso da função `property_exists` é verificado apenas se a propriedade existe e não se considera o valor atribuído.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode passar o segundo parâmetro do [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) como `true`, decodificando o seu `JSON` em um `array` associativo e utilizar [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php) para verificar se existe a `key` **nome**:

```
$json = '{
 "operacao": {
    "nome": "hugo"
 }
}';

$obj = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump(array_key_exists('nome', $obj['operacao']));
// Resulta em bool(true) ou bool(false)
```